# Apache Camel pollEnrich using selector on JMSCorrelationID

Tags: apache-camel, jms

I'm trying to use pollEnrich to consume a specific message from an endpoint based upon the **JMSCorrelationID** value. I've found many older posts that indicated that **pollEnrich** did not support this but according to the latest manual **pollEnrich** now supports dynamic urls [Camel manual for pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/pollEnrich-eip.html).

I can't however get it working in my code with a selector and I'm not sure if it is a syntax issue or if I am doing something else wrong. Initially I had it using a dynamic value in the selector but I can't even get it working with a static value.

Code snippet of my route:

```
<route id="receive_start">
    <from uri="direct:receive_start"/>
    <pollEnrich>
        <simple>seda:resources?selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'1234'</simple>
    </pollEnrich>
    <recipientList>
        <simple>direct:respond_end</simple>
    </recipientList>
</route>
```

When I pass a message through this route I get the following error:

```
Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-1582783414063-0-11 on ExchangeId: ID-1582783414063-0-10). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: seda://resources?+selector=JMSCorrelationID+%3D+%271234%27 due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: seda://resources?+selector=JMSCorrelationID+%3D+%271234%27 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{selector=JMSCorrelationID = '1234'}]
```

Without the selector I can retrieve from the resources endpoint but I need to be able to retrieve a specific message from this endpoint out of all the ones there.

The broader context here is that I am processing a message then storing a copy at another endpoint so that later messages may retrieve it if required to extract additional information from it for their own processing.

Comment: SEDA component does not support selector, it is JMS component option.

Comment: That would explain it then. Thanks. I'll try using a different queue in ActiveMQ.